# Can't pass a variable as an argument in a onClick function

Tags: javascript, escaping

I want to have a table and its cells are filled with data from MySQL.

The table have many TDs, which have an Id.

I want to pass the id of the cell to a function, so that I can edit its content:

```
document.getElementById(IndexedActionButton).innerHTML = '<input type="Button" name = "EditActionButton" id="EditActionButton" onClick="SaveUpdateToActionList(&quot;Cell_ID&quot;)" value="Edit Action" />';

function SaveUpdateToActionList(Cell) {
    alert(Cell);   
    document.getElementById(Cell).innerHTML = 'Here'; 
}
```

When I have `alert(Cell);` displayed, I see this sends the Text "Cell_ID", whereas I wanted to see the data ActionButton386 there.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the connection between the `input` element and the `td` with the ID?

Comment: It seems to be doing exactly as youve asked. SaveUpdateToActionList(&quot;Cell_ID&quot;) you are passing the string &quot;Cell_ID&quot; not  ActionButton386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the element being clicked by setting your onClick script to `SaveUpdateToActionList(this);`

Then, in the body of `SaveUpdateToActionList`, `Cell` will refer to the button that just got clicked. You can then walk up the DOM to get to the TD it belongs to.

Comment: Thank you very much!
This solves my problem. I will study this and move on.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   document.getElementById(IndexedActionButton).innerHTML = '<input type="Button" name =      "EditActionButton" id="EditActionButton" onClick="SaveUpdateToActionList()" value="Edit Action" />';

   function SaveUpdateToActionList(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);   
    document.getElementById(Cell).innerHTML = 'Here'; 
   }
```

But if i understand correctly what you are trying to do, you shoud have a single event listner that catches bubling events from all cells, rather that attaching a an onclick to each cell....

Answer (score 0):

Just register the event listener separately from specifying the `innerHTML` property:

```
Document.getElementById(IndexedActionButton).addEventListener('onclick', SaveUpdateToActionList);
```

`SaveUpdateToActionList` will be called with an event object as the first argument. You can access which element was clicked by checking the `event.target` property. For more information check out [MDN - addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) documentation